# what is the return type of an SQL SELECT query in php, is it array, object, or what?

Tags: php, sql, select, types, return

I'm documenting functions in a REST API in php but I couldn't figure out the return type of a get all query, is it array, object, or what

Comment: You can switch return types between 2 different types of array. Show your code.

Comment: `var_dump` will show you.

Comment: There are a few ways to do sql queries in php and the answer depends on what you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns an object or a boolean.

In case you have an error in your `SQL` statement then the return value will be a boolean. In general, if no errors in your `SQL` your query will return a `mysqli_result` object.

**That's an output example of a** `SQL query`:

```
class mysqli_result#2 (5) {
  public $current_field =>
  int(0)
  public $field_count =>
  int(79)
  public $lengths =>
  NULL
  public $num_rows =>
  int(1457)
  public $type =>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: if the answer is the expected one, please mark the answer, so anyone who needs this info will get the right one :)